# How do I change the avatar of a user in SDDM & KDE Plasma 5?

Tags: kde, configuration, plasma, plasma5, sddm

[image: The GUI]

I’m using *simple desktop display manager (SDDM)* & *KDE Plasma 5*. How do I configure the avatar picture of a *non-root* user, **through commands** (so that I can automate it)? How do I do the above in a terminal?

I can’t even find the configuration file, `.ini`, `.conf`, `*rc`, be it whatever. I have done `kfind` throughout the whole system and found nothing but the locations of those icon image files, which are of no use.

Answer (score 0):

If using `sudo` is an option, try this:

```bash
(
  username=test
  avatar_src=avatar.png
  avatar_dest=/var/lib/AccountsService/icons/$username

  sudo cp "$avatar_src" "$avatar_dest"
  echo "[User]" | sudo tee /var/lib/AccountsService/users/$username
  echo "Icon=$avatar_dest" | sudo tee -a /var/lib/AccountsService/users/$username
)
```

Also, here's where SDDM looks for avatars: https://github.com/roberthoffmann/sddm/blob/develop/src/greeter/UserModel.cpp#L116